# Longest element of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, coxeter-groups

Say I have a finite Weyl group, $W$, and a set of generators $S:= \{s_1,...,s_k\}$ (making $W,S$ a coxeter system) and an automorphism $\theta: W\rightarrow W$ which permutes $S$. I know that the fixed subgroup $W^\theta$ is a Weyl group generated by the longest elements in the subgroups generated by the $\theta$ orbits of the elements of $S$. Suppose I had a longest element $w$, in $W$ with length $m$. And lets say it happens that $w\in W^\theta$ and also lets say that the factorization $w = s_1...s_m$ can be grouped: $$(s_1...s_{k_1})(s_{k_1+1}...s_{k_{2}})...(s_{k_{j-1}+1}...s_{k_j})$$ in such a way that the products in parentheses are generators for $W^\theta$. Is $w$ also a longest element for $W^\theta$ with length $j$ (note that $j$ is the number of parenthetical groups in the centered line)?

If not, is there any general connection between the longest element of the big group and that of the fixed subgroup?  Or between their respective lengths?

Comment: Are you fixing the new generators in some specific way? It seemed at first that you wanted them to be the longest elements in the subgroups generated by orbits, but $w$ is itself such an element, so in that case it would get length $1$ in the subgroup.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I believe the generators are the longest elements of the parabolic subgroups generated by a single orbit. $w$ would only be a generator if $S$ was a single orbit.

Comment: Yes, correct. w has length 1 iff there is a single orbit

Comment: Your condition $w_o\in W^\theta$ is so restrictive that it will only hapen if there is precisely one $\theta$-orbit.